# Can't get an openNTF Session in java being called from an XPage - Version 10.0.1

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

I'm trying to get a session in java being called from an XPage. The old school way from version 3.0 use to work great:

```
(Session) Factory.fromLotus(NotesFactory.createSession(), Session.class, null);
```

But that's no longer available. I tried the code below that I found but I keep getting the following error:

```
***NO STACK TRACE*** - A session of type CURRENT was requested but no Factory has been defined for that type in this thread.

***NO STACK TRACE*** - Unable to get the session of type CURRENT from the session factory of type null. This probably means that you are running in an unsupported configuration or you forgot to set up your context at the start
of the operation. If you're running in XPages, check the xsp.properties of your database. If you are running in an Agent, make sure you start with a call to Factory.setSession() and pass in your lotus.domino.Session
java.lang.RuntimeException
at org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory.getSession(Factory.java:1012)
at org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory.getSession(Factory.java:859)
```

The "make sure you start with a call to Factory.setSession() and pass in your lotus.domino.Session" is misleading as setSession() is also no longer available.

```
if(!Factory.isStarted()) {
        Factory.startup();          
    }
    if (!Factory.isInitialized()) {
        System.out.println("Factory.initThread");
        Factory.initThread(new Factory.ThreadConfig(new Fixes[0], AutoMime.WRAP_32K, true));
    }

    Session session = Factory.getSession();
```

I've installed the OpenNTF API using the Update Site and confirmed they're loaded with the "tell http osgi ss openntf" command. I had an initial issue where it couldn't resolve the Factory, so I copied the four jar files to the ext directory and it solved that issue:

`org.openntf.domino.rest_10.0.1.201905061230.jar`

`org.openntf.domino.xsp_10.0.1.201905061230.jar`

`org.openntf.domino_10.0.1.201905061230.jar`

`org.openntf.formula_10.0.1.201905061230.jar`

I also tried to hand in a Domino Session in the Factory.startup() call and it still didn't work.

Thanks,
Scott

Domino 10.0.1 FP1
`openNTF API: OpenNTF-Domino-API-10.0.1.zip`

Code where the issue is. This is being called from an XPage. The call is:

```
<xp:label value="#{javascript:sessionBean.getCoreUser().getUserId();}"/>
```

This fires the SessionBean Constructor, which calls the startLogging method. That method checks to see if "DebugMode" is turned on. If yes, all debug statements are written to the OpenLog.

```
private void startLogging() {
        System.out.println("Start OpenLog Logging");

        Session session = (Session) ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "openSession");
        System.out.println("Session: " + session);      

        try {
            ViewEntry valueEntry = session.getCurrentDatabase().getView("SystemConfig").getFirstEntryByKey("DebugMode");
            if (valueEntry != null)             
                SessionBean.debugMode = ("true".equalsIgnoreCase((String) valueEntry.getColumnValue("SetupValue")) ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE);

            System.out.println("Debug Mode set to: " + debugMode);          
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in Start OpenLog Logging");
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `Factory.getSession()`?

Comment: @Per Henrik Lausten I did try the flat 'getSession()' call initially, but received a 'Factory is not initialized for this thread' error, which started me down the 'Factory.isStarted(), 'Factory.isInitialized()'... path.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this nowadays in a servlet plugin is to have this in the `service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)` method:

```java
Factory.setSessionFactory(() -> AppUtil.getSession(), SessionType.CURRENT);
```

Where `AppUtil.getSession()` is a method that tries to find a session for the current context, checking an XPages environment if available, then `ContextInfo.getUserSession()`, and finally calling `NotesFactory.createSession()` if it can't find anything.

After setting that, `Factory.getSession()` will use the provided override instead of its normal behavior.

Comment: See also ODA Starter Servlet for getting it in a plugin

Comment: Hey Jesse, I'm having trouble finding the AppUtil class. I did look at the ODA Starter Servlet, as Paul suggested, but a search in there didn't return AppUtil anywhere. I also tried Arun's suggestions and I still show session as null. Is there a reason the one line Factory from lotus was removed? Thanks, Scott.

Comment: “AppUtil” is an anonymized name of a utility class I use in my client project - it’s a placeholder name in this case. The gist of it is that you can set the CURRENT SessionFactory to something that will do the thing you want, in your example going through NotesFactory.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is what Jesse has suggested. Use variable resolver. I am getting ODA sessions like this for my application. Here is the updated code to fetch ODA session or domino session as available:

```
public static Session getSessionAsSigner() {
    Session s = (Session) ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "openSessionAsSigner");
    if (null == s) {
        s = (Session) Factory.getWrapperFactory().fromLotus((lotus.domino.Session)ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "sessionAsSigner"), Session.SCHEMA, null);
    }
    return s;
}

public static Session getSession() {
    Session s = (Session) ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "openSession");
    if (null == s) {
        s = (Session) Factory.getWrapperFactory().fromLotus((lotus.domino.Session)ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "session"), Session.SCHEMA, null);
    }
    return s;
}
```

I have created a Utils class with static functions for this purpose only.

Comment: Hi Arun, I tried these and I'm still getting session = null. What am I missing here. I added the grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; }; to the policy file early on as I was getting a security error, so it's not that. Thanks for the help, Scott

Comment: Can you provide some code and where you are trying it? Also check in your Designer Help-->Support-->View Trace for any issue while installing the plugins.

Comment: Added code to OP. On the Trace Viewer, I see a severe error: com.ibm.rcp.personality.framework.internal.RCPWorkbenchAdvisor
eventLoopException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSiteDragAndDropServiceImpl$MergedDropTarget$1.dragLeave(Unknown Source) I don't think this applies to the issue.

Comment: Check updated code in my answer above. It checks if ODA session is available o rnot. If not, it wraps the domino session into ODA session (courtesy frostillicus framework created by Jesse).

Comment: OP is Original Post or Original Poster. I added your code and tried both `getSession()` and `getSessionAsSigner()` and both returned - `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory is not initialized for this thread!` I changed everything to support `lotus.domino` and changed `session = DominoUtils.getCurrentSession();` and that works fine but I want to use the openNTF api as we have for years. This is a new 9.0.1 FP8 to 10.0.1 FP1 upgrade. Something may have gone bad in the upgrade so I think I'll uninstall and re-install 10.0.1 FP1 clean.

Comment: OK, I did a complete wipe on my client and reinstall of 10.0.1 and added FP1. I installed the OpenNTF and OpenLog 8.1. I was getting a Manifest error not being able to fine the plugins when I selected them in the Page Generation, XPages Library and saved. In Preferences, Plug-in Development, Target Platform, Running Platform I added a reference to the plug-ins ...\applications\eclipse and that solved that issue. My client is good, but I now get this error on the server when I include any of the plug-in libraries... see next comment

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.faces.event.PhaseListener&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.initModule(ComponentModule.java:485)`  At this point I'm thinking it's easier to kill a White Walker, than get this working.

Comment: OK, after a whole lot of dick'n around (technical term), we got it sorted. It has something to do with the server upgrade from 9.0.1 FP8 to 10.0.1 FP1. As the error was java related, we decided to remove the jvm directory 'Lotus\Domino\jvm' from the server and reinstall Domino 10.0.1. We then added the FP1 and restarted. Everything came-up clean and the code works with just the `Factory.getSession();` call. It also works with the static calls `getSession()` and `getSessionAsSigner()` supplied by @Arun. We have 30+ servers to upgrade so this was good for us to figure out. Thanks for the help.